# i import PyNaCl, but whenever i upgrade python to a newer version, it is being removed ( Python )

Tags: python, upgrade, replit, pynacl

i am using [Repl.it](https://repl.it) and i am having trouble using PyNaCl in Python.

i firstly install the package. `pip install PyNaCl`

then i import it. `import nacl`

PyNaCl works properly and i have no problem with that but whenever there is a newer version, and i upgrade or it upgrades by itself, it also removes PyNaCl.

i make sure if it is in the list and yes, it is there at first but after upgrading, when i check the list (`pip list`) it is not there anymore. so i always need to install it again. and it is a total disaster when making a discord bot.

how can i manage to make it install PyNaCl while upgrading ( there is no such thing with other packages i imported )

Answer (score 0):

your repls > packages > search 'pynacl' > add the first result